# How to minimize javascript events

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I need to reduce the number of javascript events on a page of my web application. Would it be better to migrate these to a onclick attribute on the HTML element?

e.g.

```
 <input ... onclick="myJavascript"/>
```

as opposed to

```
 YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(element, 'click', handleElementClick, eventObject);
```

The issue is that Javascript events are the most resource intensive code that I see in my Javascript profiler (I have used both Developer tools and Firebug). I want to reduce the load, and I am wondering what the best way to do this is.

Comment: hmm, not sure what is being asked here.

Comment: Well, they're going to be called either way (assuming of course you don't go and stick them to a wholly unrelated event, which is propably not what you want), so...

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are currently assigning events to elements?

Comment: The only way to reduce the number of *event handler bindings* would be *event delegation*. But you have to clarify what you actually want. Your question is a bit vague. Both code snippets above do the same, the bind an event handler to an element. However, with the second one, you can reuse the event handler better, which consumes less memory.

Comment: Why do you want to change the way you have bound your events? What's your motivation?  Are you experiencing performance problems?

Comment: Once a browser finishes rendering a page, there's almost nothing happening _except_ the Javascript event handlers. So from a _relative_ point of view if you look at the percentage of time in event handlers in a profiler it can be very high, but nevertheless from an _absolute_ point of view there may not be any problem. Fairly often desktop Javascript profilers tell you more about what kind of intelligence your page is providing than they do about which functions need recoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better solution would be to use event delegation, which registers ONE event. You just need to sniff out element to determine if you need to take action. This is considered the best way to improve the performance of javascript events and not pollute the DOM. This way would also work for DOM element added to the page with Ajax, meaning you do not need to rebind events to the new elements:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (target === myElement) {
        // do something here


}
```

Comment: thanks man, I started looking into it and http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/v0114/examples/event/delegation.php is really helping me out

Comment: YUI 2.x has event delegation built into an easy API. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#delegate

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should keep your event code inside of your JavaScript code instead of putting it in your HTML. This allows for much easier debugging in the future because it keeps all of the difference pieces of logic in separate locations; it's usually considered desirable to have all structure in the HTML, all presentation in the CSS, and all client-side functionality in the JavaScript. Mixing the different layers isn't necessarily bad, it's usually just an unnecessary complication.

However, in a general sense, the best method is the delegation method, which was posted before I could get around to typing it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to attach more than one handler, the second method is better i think, and there are more options, depends on the framework you use